# Cordova plugin for WhatsApp: open chat window

Tags: cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app, whatsapp, cordova-ios

I'm building Cordova ios app.
I've tried these 2 plugins to open WhatsApp: [First](https://github.com/ranjitpandit/whatsapp-phonegap-plugin/blob/master/README.md) and [Second](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin).
Both of them are really helpful for opening the WhatsApp for a particular contact. But not in one go.

That means it opens the WhatsApp for the first click but not the chat window for a particular contact. It does so in the second click and beyond.

What I understood is this, that in first click it save (creating a new contact) the contact and opens the WhatsApp and then WhatsApp contacts gets updated. And when we click the second time it opens the chat window for a particular contact.

I'm looking for a cordova plugin which updates the WhatsApp contacts. For now, I didn't found any.

If you guys have any idea about this please share, it really helps.

My code:

```
    this.whatsappHandler = function() {
      var that = this;
      if(cordova.platformId !== 'browser') {
        $("#headerbar_"+this.getCurPage().id+" [data-whatsapp]").each(function () {
          $(this).click(function () {
            var phno = $(this).data('whatsapp');
            var name = $(this).data('name');
            function onSuccess(contacts) {
              console.log('Found ' + contacts.length + ' contacts.');
              if(!contacts.length) {
                var contact = navigator.contacts.create({"displayName": name});
                var phoneNumbers = [];
                console.log(phno);
                phoneNumbers[0] = new ContactField('mobile', phno, true);
                contact.phoneNumbers = phoneNumbers;
                contact.save();
                that.showToast({
                    message: "Contact saved. Tap on WhatsApp again",
                    duration: "long",
                    position: "bottom"
                });
              } else {
                that.openWhatsapp(contacts[0]);
              }
            };
            function onError(contactError) {
              console.log('Finding Contact Error!');
            };
            var options      = new ContactFindOptions();
            options.filter   = phno;
            options.multiple = true;
            options.hasPhoneNumber = true;
            var fields       = [navigator.contacts.fieldType.phoneNumbers];
            navigator.contacts.find(fields, onSuccess, onError, options);

          });
        });
      }
    };

    this.openWhatsapp = function(contact) {
      this.showToast({
          message: "Opening WhatsApp...",
          duration: "long",
          position: "bottom"
      });
      setTimeout(function(){
        if(cordova.platformId === 'ios')
          window.location = 'whatsapp://send?abid='+contact.id;
        else if(cordova.platformId === 'android')
          cordova.plugins.Whatsapp.send(contact.phoneNumbers[0].value);
      },1500);
    };
```